# `/var/lock` equivalent on OSX

Tags: compatibility, unix

`/var/lock` doesn't exist in OSX, so where do the lock files / PID files go?

Answer (score 3):

`/private/var/run` is the place for system/root level pid files to live on OSX (Darwin)

Locking is more complicated (or simple depending on your POV) with the system/API arbitrating device locks rather than writing them to the filesystem.

Do consider the implications of fast user switching and the documentation on [Multiple User Environments](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPMultipleUsers/BPMultipleUsers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000180i) or simply calling `NSTemporaryDirectory` if your locking happens in user space or the application can be fired up more than one at a time.

Comment: Note that /var/run is only for system processes, and is only writable by root & the daemon group.  For user-level processes, something like /tmp is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Wherever you want to there is no standard place for lock files in Unix. Only the Linux  Filesystem Hierarchy Standard provides for /var/loc See [Wikipaedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) for some examples of the hierarchies used from there is [FreeBsd](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hier&sektion=7)

As for direct OSX references see [NSDistributedLock](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDistributedLock_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which gives no directions or example of paths to be used and [shlock](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/shlock.1.html) which gives the BSD example in /tmp